# Icon on stackexchange.com site stats is not yet updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It's been a number of hours now, so it's not caching, but, on the main [stackexchange.com sites page](http://stackexchange.com/sites) the icon for Movies&TV is a sort of half-mix of new and beta design:

[image]

It's hard to believe that's a victim of caching.... but perhaps it is.

Still, it should be brought to someone's attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's been cached, eventually you'll see the new icon. meanwhile you can cache break it manually here: http://cdn.sstatic.net/movies/img/icon-48.png?v=whatever

Comment: I can see the updated version with that link. I have no idea where the caching is happening, but yes, it is somewhere.

Comment: Is logo on tour is also due to cache http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour ??

Comment: @AnkitSharma yes. i'll ask our devs to do a manual server side purge today.

Comment: It'll update on its own eventually, just give it some time.

Comment: Removed the accept, for the moment. It's now been more than 24 hours, and I still see the original problem.

Comment: I am still seeing the Beta Icon as well

Comment: @rolfl I'm contacting our dev to purge this. it's weird because I'm seeing the new one.

Comment: I have now refreshed, and the icon has updated. Thanks.

Comment: The icon is updated now, but seeing that it is a largely red symbol inside a red blurb, I'm not sure it really does much juistice to our nice popcorn box icon. I know our primary color is the red, but I wonder if it would look much nicer to put the red popcorn box into a lighter background blurb, maybe this light brown greyish color from the color scheme (the one that is the background of all those SE links at the bottom of the main site, right above the blue box), or maybe even the light blue from at the bottom of the main site.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I told our dev to update the movies site bubble bgcolor to a lighter red so the logo would contrast more. expect the change to go live tomorrow

Comment: @Jin Though, lighter red is not really part of our initial color scheme, which could make it a bit inconseistent. Why not just another color from the existing color scheme? But nevermind.