# M&TV icon in browser tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Minor thing - when browsing the meta site, the M&TV icon now shows a little popcorn icon:

[image]

However, on the main site it's still the old image:

[image]

I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that this is meant to be changed too and thus is a bug.

P.S. LOVING the new design!

**Edit**

Just saw [this post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/icon-on-stackexchange-com-site-stats-is-not-yet-updated). Is this a caching issue too?

Comment: Looks caching to me because i can see orange popcorn tub.

Comment: Fair enough then

Comment: On few places like tour etc i am seeing old icon too.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely a cache issue. I'll ask our devs to do a server side purge today.